# How to consider that observer.next(something) got the value before the running the observer.complete()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm creating an app with Angular. On the component I have resolver to pre-load data. here is the resolver's code:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
return Observable.create(observer => {
  const searchProductsRequest = this.journeyDataService.searchProductsRequest;
    this.basketService.reset();
    this.progressService.subscribe(
    this.productsPublicApiService.getRecommendedProductCategoriesUsingGET(searchProductsRequest.vrn,
        searchProductsRequest.postcode),
      (response) => {
        // we save work type list
        observer.next(response.categories);
      },
      // this.handleServerErrors.bind(this)
      (err) => console.error(err)
    );
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Then in the component I'm doing

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.productCategoryList = this.route.snapshot.data.productCategoryList;
   console.log('resolve', this.productCategoryList);
 }
```

And here resolve is null. So the problem is that response from server comes later then I run complete and so I don't have the data to display.

Comment: Why do you need to manually create an observer? Why not just `return this.productsPublicApiService.getRecommendedProductCategoriesUsingGET(...)` (a weird name, how else would you get them? Why force the transport layer to leak like that?)

Comment: you complete the stream before async code runs...

Comment: @seanplwong, yes, but I don't know how I should wait for async code completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just put complete call to "next" handler like this:

```
(response) => {
        // we save work type list
        observer.next(response.categories);
        observer.complete();
      },
```

however there is most likely a more usual way to handle your task, but to implement it understanding of "what `getRecommendedProductCategoriesUsingGET` and `progressService.subscribe` are" is required

Comment: thanks. Can you please explain how it works? the mechanism

Comment: rxjs is built in that way that after calling complete you won't recieve any event in subscription. in your code complete is called just after the subscription is done, not when the result har returned from backend. it is fixed by moving complete call to the next handler